# Optimized way to select items from a Collection excluding a list of certain member using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I will explain it with an example.

Suppose I have a List of Student Object, Where Student Class is,

```
class Student
{
    public int RollNo {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}
```

and a List containing special StateIds

```
List<int> specialStateIds;
```

Now I want to extract List of RollIds from Students List which doesn't belong to specialStates. Currently I'm doing it as following.

```
List<int> NonSpacialRollIds = Students.Where(s => 
      !specialStateIds.Contains(s.StateId)).Select(s => s.RoleIds).ToList();
```

But somehow I feel, It can be optimize further using Linq and Contains extension method of Collections can be avoided.

Comment: If `specialStateIds` is already sorted, and `Students` is sorted by `StateId` then some non-Linq code could do it efficiently, but if they are not sorted then Sergey's answer is the proper way.

Comment: @ Dialecticus: Does 'Contains' uses binary search internally? any alternative to 'Contains'?

Comment: `HashSet.Contains` does some calculation magic. Explanation cannot be both simple and comprehensive. Start from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). You pay with more time during creation of `HashSet`, but you gain time when using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create set of state ids for faster search, because `Contains()` operation on hash set is O(1) and `Contains` on list is O(N):

```
HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(specialStateIds);

List<int> NonSpacialRollIds = Students.Where(s => !ids.Contains(s.StateId))
                                      .Select(s => s.RoleIds)
                                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Damn, too fast, You are not Lazy *(lazyberezovsky)* any more :P

Comment: Can you please explain why your method is better?